# Generate start and end dates in a date range Oracle

Tags: sql, database, oracle

I made the below query and getting the following output.But the dates should not be consecutive,the new quater should start with next day.

```
SELECT x.* , end_dt-st_dt FROM 
(SELECT 12-(LEVEL-1) AS Quater ,trunc(sysdate) - 90*LEVEL AS st_dt,trunc(sysdate) - 90*(LEVEL-1) AS end_dt
FROM dual
connect BY LEVEL <= 12
ORDER BY 1
) x

1   8/17/2011   11/15/2011  90
2   11/15/2011  2/13/2012   90
3   2/13/2012   5/13/2012   90
4   5/13/2012   8/11/2012   90
5   8/11/2012   11/9/2012   90
6   11/9/2012   2/7/2013    90
7   2/7/2013    5/8/2013    90
8   5/8/2013    8/6/2013    90
9   8/6/2013    11/4/2013   90
10  11/4/2013   2/2/2014    90
11  2/2/2014    5/3/2014    90
12  5/3/2014    8/1/2014    90
```

EXPECTED output :

```
....
...
    10  11/2/2013   1/31/2014   90
    11  2/1/2014    5/2/2014    90
    12  5/3/2014    8/1/2014    90
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this is what you want? I am not sure

```
SELECT x.* , end_dt-st_dt FROM 
(SELECT 12-(LEVEL-1) AS Quater ,
(CASE WHEN ( trunc(sysdate) - 90*LEVEL = TO_DATE('17-AUG-11','DD-MON-YY')) 
THEN trunc(sysdate) - 90*LEVEL
ELSE trunc(sysdate)+1 - 90*LEVEL
END) AS st_dt,trunc(sysdate) - 90*(LEVEL-1) AS end_dt
FROM dual
connect BY LEVEL <= 12
ORDER BY 1
) x;
```

My output:

1   17-AUG-11    15-NOV-11  90

2   16-NOV-11    13-FEB-12  89

3   14-FEB-12    13-MAY-12  89

4   14-MAY-12    11-AUG-12  89

5   12-AUG-12    09-NOV-12  89

6   10-NOV-12    07-FEB-13  89

7   08-FEB-13    08-MAY-13  89

8   09-MAY-13    06-AUG-13  89

9   07-AUG-13    04-NOV-13  89

10  05-NOV-13    02-FEB-14  89

11  03-FEB-14    03-MAY-14  89

12  04-MAY-14    01-AUG-14  89